# "Trailing comma" error is showing up in VSCode

Tags: json, visual-studio-code

This happened when I tried to change setting.json. Now, I can't solve it.

[image]

Comment: It may be the fact that after the comma you have written nothing?

Comment: That's just a warning. Feel free to ignore it.

Comment: @phuzi I am totally okay but would you know the origin (clearly curiosity)? All I can guess is that he wrote comma but didn't add more elements after

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/8967612)

Comment: Trailing commas are forbidden in true [JSON](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON). What exactly do you mean when you say you "tried to change" it?

Answer (score 0):

That is a known bug, see https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/126330

It states that it is fixed in the Insiders build and should be out in v1.58 which is due out soon.